# Powershell script to save user credentials in a xml file

Tags: powershell

I have a power shell script that when run will prompt the user to:

1. Select a folder location
2. select a file name
3. enter credentials

This then exports those credentials in a xml file. Although this requires 3 prompts to the user before is complete. Looking to find if there is a better way to approach this. For example, having a single prompt for the user.

```
###########################################################
# Create a file containing encrypted credentials
###########################################################

clear

Function Get-Folder($initialDirectory)
{
    #User selected folder location
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")|Out-Null

    $path = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $path.Description = "Select a folder"
    $path.rootfolder = "MyComputer"

    if($path.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
    {
        $location += $path.SelectedPath
    }

    #User selected file name
    [void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')

    $title = 'File Name'
    $msg   = 'Please enter your file name'

    $text = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($msg, $title)

    #Open prompt for user to enter credentials and export to xml file
    Get-Credential | Export-Clixml "$location\Credentials-$text.xml"

}

Get-Folder
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Instead of letting the user (1) choose a folder and (2) choose a file name, you can just present the user with a **Save File Dialog**. It also warns the user if he tries to overwrite an existing file.
- If the user cancels one of your dialogs, you should cancel the script rather than continue with invalid data.

---

```
$dialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
$dialog.FileName = "Credentials.xml"
$dialog.Filter = "XML files (*.xml)|*.xml|All files|*.*"

if ($dialog.ShowDialog() -ne "OK")
{
    exit
}

...

Get-Credential | Export-Clixml $dialog.FileName
```